# why does grep '\;.' expand to grep '\''\;.'\''' when executed over ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

```
$cat test.sh
ssh HOST -l root -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q "/bin/bash -l -c /bin/env | grep -w PATH | grep '\;.'"

$bash -x test.sh
+ ssh HOST -l root -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -q '/bin/bash -l -c /bin/env | grep -w PATH | grep '\''\;.'\'''
```

Answer (score 2):

It's nothing to do with SSH.  The `-x` argument to bash is that of bash's `set` command, which displays the command's arguments in expanded form. This is why the double quoted strings are displayed as single quoted strings.

```
$ cat test.sh
echo "here are 'some single quotes' inside double quotes"

$ bash -x test.sh
+ echo 'here are '\''some single quotes'\'' inside double quotes'
here are 'some single quotes' inside double quotes
```